# Checking If ListView<String> contains a String - JavaFX

Tags: java, string, listview, javafx, contains

I am making a JavaFX application in which I have a `ComboBox<String>`, so when I click on any item in the ComboBox I added that item to be added to a `String course` and then appended my `ListView<String>` with course String.

But at the same time, I do not want to add any duplicates to the ListView.

So what is the possible way to do that?
Is there any way to check if ListView contains it?
I tried but I couldn't use contains with ListView and `String course`

```
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> select_subject;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> course_list;

    public void diplaysubjects() {
            String course = select_subject.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                   course_list.getItems().add(course.toString());
    }
```

Comment: _I couldn't use contains_ why not, an observableList is-a list ;) btw: a) add course to both combo- and listView, with appropriate custom cells (vs a String) b) stick to java naming conventions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ObservableList.contains` method to quickly check any occurrence of a similar item:

```
public void diplaysubjects() {
    String item = select_subject.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    ObservableList<String> courses = course_list.getItems(); // Only here to clarify the code

    if (!courses.contains(item))
        courses.add(item);
}
```

I don't know which pattern did you use for your code but if it is a MVC-like, I suggest you to work directly with the model's observable list instead of calling `course_list.getItems()`.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use observable list with ListView.
Do like this

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ComboBox<String> select_subject;

@FXML
private ListView<String> course_list;

private ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    course_list.setItems(list);
}

public void diplaysubjects() {
    String course = select_subject.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    //Instead of adding directly to listview add to observablelist
    //course_list.getItems().add(course.toString());
    list.add(course);
}

//To check the list contains the item
private boolean doesExists(String element){
    return list.contains(element);
}
}
```

Comment: no reason to a) keep an alias to the listView's items b) bloat the code by a method around contains (as long as it does nothing else)

Answer (score -1):

You can add an arrayList() where you add the String if it doesn't contain it and then add it to the ListView.

```java
@FXML
    private ComboBox<String> select_subject;

    @FXML
    private ListView<String> course_list;

    public void diplaysubjects() {
            ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<>();
      
            String course = select_subject.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
             if (!s.contains(course)){
                 s.add(course);
                 course_list.getItems().add(course.toString());
             }
    }
```

Comment: Well .. that's utterly wrong: a) the if-block will always be executed (because s is an empty Array) b) even if it were not (after re-organizing the code), why would you want to keep a duplicate of the listView's items c) string.toString is - at best - redundant